# Objective-C append to string not working NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, parsing, http

I am trying to parse some XML data and append the parsed data into an NSString object. I have successfully parsed the XML data using NSXMLParser, but when I log the value of the string called `arrayString`, I just get the value of the first `<name>`, instead of all of them. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
(void)parseWithData:(NSData *)data {
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
[parser setDelegate:self];
//You might want to consider additional params like:
[parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
[parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
//And then finally (which activates the delegates):
[parser parse];
NSLog(@"The content of the array is%@",childElement);

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI             qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
 currentElement = nil;
 currentElement = [elementName copy];
 if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"row"]) {
    //This means the parser has entered the XML parent element named: xmlParentElement
    //All of the child elements that need to be stored in the array should have their own IVARs and declarations.
    childElement = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
 }
 }

 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
   //For all child elements, run this if statement.
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
    [childElement appendString:string];
    NSLog(string);
    [arrayString stringByAppendingString:string];
   // NSLog(arrayString);


   }
```

And I parse the data by calling these methods:

```
  NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
  [self parseWithData:data];
```

Comment: You can append any string to string only when the first string has some value ... it can be `@"";` too. `NSString *str1 = @"";` then you can use `stringByAppendingString:` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stringByAppendingString` function returns a `NSString`. It doesn't alter the receiver.

You need to fix your use of `stringByAppendingString`. For example, in `foundCharacters`, replace this:

```
[arrayString stringByAppendingString:string];
```

With this:

```
arrayString = [arrayString stringByAppendingString:string];
```

Apple's [documentation on `stringByAppendingString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingString%3a):

> stringByAppendingString:
>
> Returns a new string made by appending a given string to the receiver.

Also, when appending strings, don't forget to initialize the string before you append to it.

Comment: Thanks, but now it the value of arrayString is null

Comment: But why is the value of it null?

Comment: @Coder101, what variable is NULL? I thought `arrayString` was the problem. You might need to fix your use of `stringByAppendingString` everywhere else, including with `childElement`.

Comment: @Coder101, ah yes. Glad you figured it out. :) I updated my answer to include initialization for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the stringByAppendingString method creates a new NSString. Try this instead of that:

```
arrayString = [arrayString stringByAppendingString:string];
```

Comment: Yes, thats what @MarcusAdams said a few minutes ago, but thanks :D